# Ajax ready/notready button without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I am pretty much new to coding but i am learning along the way. i managed to make my buttons in php etcetera but ofcource this refreshes the page which made it very annoying.

I looked around and came to know Ajax. i managed to get certain page parts to auto refresh it's data and i also managed to make a button that changes it's test from Ready / Not Ready and sending data to a php file that processes it and updates the database.

However i am facing with one problem. for example, if a user uses the button sometimes and the database value is set to Ready. if they refresh the page. or close and come back the button would say it's default value *Ready* while the database already has it set Ready.

The eventual goal is that a user can set his status to ready or not ready for a game match. where the database gets updated so that info can be shown to other users.

I will post my code below, sorry if the code is a mess i can understand it very well might be since i took the pieces from examples on the internet.

```
var xmlHttp_five = AJAX();
function ajaxFunction(pid) {
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if(xmlHttp_five) { 
    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    xmlHttp_five.open("POST","includes/gather_buttons.php",true); //calling testing.php using POST method
    xmlHttp_five.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp_five.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp_five.send("txtname=" + txtname.value + "&pid=" + pid); //Posting txtname to PHP File
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlHttp_five.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlHttp_five.status == 200) {

        if (document.myForm.button1.value == "Ready") {
            document.myForm.button1.value = "Not Ready";
            document.myForm.txtname.value = "Waiting";
        } else {
            document.myForm.button1.value = "Ready";
            document.myForm.txtname.value = "Ready";
        }
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
}
```

and the form below

```
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type='hidden' name='txtname' id='txtname' value='Ready'/>
    <input type='button' class='button2' id='button1' value='Ready' onclick='ajaxFunction($pid);' />
</form>
```

If i need to give more info please say so, sorry if i am not supposed to post this here.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Johan

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand your problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should be generated by server-side script. So when user refreshes page, he gets actual data from the database.

Otherwise if you can't generate form by server-side script, you should use preloader: button's value initially should be "loading..." and script should request the value by Ajax.

Comment: thanks, i managed to get this to work with a check before the form to see what the last action of the user was.